# How to get Table to center?

Tags: tables

```
    \section{Technical Skills}
\vspace{1mm}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Programming \\ Languages\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ Technical:}} C, MATLAB, Python\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Editing:}} Photoshop\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                    \\ \midrule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Software\\ Packages\end{tabular}}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ AutoCad:}} Design and Drafting\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Ansys:}} Finite Element Software\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ ArcGis:}} Analyse Spatial Data\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Qualk2k:}} Surface Water Quality Modeling\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ SWMM:}} Strom Water Management \& Modeling\end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}[![][1]][1]
```

[image: This is what i get when i compile in Overleaf]

Comment: Are you in [twocolumn] mode?  If so, he table won't fit into one column.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Specifically, we'd like to receive code that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. We call this a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764). Can you do that? It'll help get you answers much quicker than posting just code snippets.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

If you add document class and loads the package boooktabs, the table compiles fine and in centre. If you prefer the tabular after the heading, try to add the option `\begin{table}[h!]` to the table environment (it may work, but not always):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Technical Skills}
\vspace{1mm}

Some text

\begin{table}  %% Add option [h!] if you prefer the table after the heading.
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Programming \\ Languages\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ Technical:}} C, MATLAB, Python\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Editing:}} Photoshop\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                    \\ \midrule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Software\\ Packages\end{tabular}}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ AutoCad:}} Design and Drafting\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Ansys:}} Finite Element Software\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ ArcGis:}} Analyse Spatial Data\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Qualk2k:}} Surface Water Quality Modeling\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ SWMM:}} Strom Water Management \& Modeling\end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

With option `[h!]`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In particular, I had a lot of problems with `table` environment. If you don't need "Table X", don't need to use `\begin{table}`. If you need this, you can use one of those packages: [`caption`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf), [`capt-of`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/capt-of/capt-of.pdf) or the class [`memoir`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/capt-of/capt-of.pdf).

A example with no `table` and using `caption` and `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Technical Skills}
\vspace{1mm}

Some text

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Programming \\ Languages\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ Technical:}} C, MATLAB, Python\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Editing:}} Photoshop\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                    \\ \midrule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Software\\ Packages\end{tabular}}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ AutoCad:}} Design and Drafting\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Ansys:}} Finite Element Software\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ ArcGis:}} Analyse Spatial Data\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Qualk2k:}} Surface Water Quality Modeling\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ SWMM:}} Strom Water Management \& Modeling\end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{15mm}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Programming \\ Languages\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ Technical:}} C, MATLAB, Python\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Editing:}} Photoshop\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                    \\ \midrule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Software\\ Packages\end{tabular}}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ AutoCad:}} Design and Drafting\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Ansys:}} Finite Element Software\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ ArcGis:}} Analyse Spatial Data\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Qualk2k:}} Surface Water Quality Modeling\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ SWMM:}} Strom Water Management \& Modeling\end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}

\vspace{15mm}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Name of table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Programming \\ Languages\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ Technical:}} C, MATLAB, Python\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Editing:}} Photoshop\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                    \\ \midrule
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Software\\ Packages\end{tabular}}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} $\bullet${\textbf{ AutoCad:}} Design and Drafting\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Ansys:}} Finite Element Software\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ ArcGis:}} Analyse Spatial Data\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ Qualk2k:}} Surface Water Quality Modeling\\  $\bullet${\textbf{ SWMM:}} Strom Water Management \& Modeling\end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```